# Creating Universal Link [Deep Link] for Ionic Cordova application sent as a mail

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, deep-linking

I have an **Android & IOS** application developed using cordova. I have a scenario where I have to open my mobile application from a link sent as a **Mail**.

The plugin I am using is **Cordova Universal Links Plugin** and also I following the same method to include the link and open the application from the link.

The link for the plugin is [here.](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin#cordova-config-preferences) When I try to open the app, its failing. How do I create a link which is sent as a mail to open the mobile application?

JS Code is

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    // Bind Event Listeners
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        console.log('Device is ready for work');
        universalLinks.subscribe('openNewsListPage', app.onNewsListPageRequested);
        universalLinks.subscribe('openNewsDetailedPage', app.onNewsDetailedPageRequested);

        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    },

    // openNewsListPage Event Handler
    onNewsListPageRequested: function (eventData) {
        console.log('Showing list of awesome news.');

        // do some work to show list of news
    },

    // openNewsDetailedPage Event Handler
    onNewsDetailedPageRequested: function (eventData) {
        console.log('Showing to user details page: ' + eventData.path);

        // do some work to show detailed page
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Config.xml

```
<universal-links>
<host name="myhost.com">
  <path url="/news/" event="openNewsListPage" />
  <path url="/news/*" event="openNewsDetailedPage" />
</host>
```

Comment: Do your links work everywhere else except in email? Which email app are you using? Many of them are not compatible with Universal Links.

Comment: did you manage to solve ?
can you help me in this